# Printing number and string in the same line with assembly

Tags: string, loops, assembly, numbers, call

```
%include "asm_io.inc"
;
; initialized data is put in the .data segment
;
segment .data
str : db "Print",10,0

; uninitialized data is put in the .bss segment
;
segment .bss

;
; code is put in the .text segment
;
segment .text
        global  asm_main
asm_main:
        enter   0,0               ; setup routine
        pusha
; put your code below this comment.
      mov eax,1
      mov ecx,10 
      
                
L1:   call print_int
      call print_nl
      add eax,1
      cmp eax,10
      loop L1
        
; don't delete anything following this comment
        popa
        mov     eax, 0            ; return back to C
        leave                     
        ret
```

This is an assembly code that prints a loop to increment a counter from 1 to 10. I wanted to include a string "Print" and print that in the same line with the numbers so the result shows like Print 1, Print 2, ... Print 10 instead of just numbers. I tried to store string and use call read_char and call print_char but it doesn't seem to be working. Is there perhaps another way to print string and number in the same line?

Comment: Note that your string has an embedded newline.

Comment: @Jester Are you talking about "10,0" after the Print?

Comment: The `10` specifically.

Comment: @Jester Ok, I got that but I'm still not sure how to put the string in the same line with the numbers in a loop.

Comment: If you get rid of the newline it will be on the same line.